# How to restrict user creation on Mac from System Settings?

Tags: macos, terminal, user-account, system-settings

I use my mac with **admin** user, which is the only user on the device. I just want to restrict user creation from the "**User and Groups**" in **System Settings** or **Preference**. Or even if the admin can use "**Add Account**" option, the newly created user should not be accessible. (Not from the GUI at least.)

Comment: If you are the only user, why do you need to stop yourself from creating user accounts?

Comment: @benwiggy Maybe he shares this account with his wife/kids/etc and wants to keep them from mucking around with it?

Comment: @luckman212 In which case, the best policy would be to give everyone their own accounts.

Comment: To satisfy your curiosity: I use a blocker app for me and I don't want me to bypass the app by creating another user. (Here, "**I**" is my friend. He is not a techy. Now, I'm going to disable it for him and not going to tell how to undo it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First method:**
The command below will disable the Users & Groups preference pane (for all users including admin). Tested on Ventura 13.1 and Catalina.

```bash
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences DisabledPreferencePanes -array "com.apple.preferences.users"
```

To undo:

```bash
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences DisabledPreferencePanes
```

**Second Method:**
There is a more robust method that leverages `.mobileconfig` Configuration Profiles (see [rtrouton/profiles • GitHub](https://github.com/rtrouton/profiles/blob/main/DisableiCloudPreferencePane/Disable%20iCloud%20Preference%20Pane.mobileconfig) for an example which blocks access to iCloud preferences). This requires the machine to be enrolled in an MDM such as Jamf, Addigy, etc. One can also manually create/deploy the profiles using [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1037126344).

A benefit to using Profiles is that the settings can be targeted at specific Users instead of the "sledgehammer" approach in the first method.

Comment: The first method gave a desired solution for my issue. I'll keep the second method in my mind for future. Thanks for so much for your contribution.